# Drupal Exclude taxonomy listing pages from search

Tags: php, drupal, search, taxonomy, drupal-5

I have a Drupal 5 site that needs to have has taxonomny listing pages excluded in the search results.  For instance http://site.com/category/role/guest-speaker returns a listing of all of the nodes tagged with guest-speak in the vocabulary role.

I tried Advanced Search module. This just prevents searching for terms.

I then had a hunch that the [lullabot tutorial](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/hiding-content-drupals-search-system) would be of use, but don't think that I can filter on type.

Any ideas?

Comment: Excluded from the Drupal site's own search function or from Google's search result?

Comment: Ideally both, but I'll give you the bounty for excluding it from Druapal's search.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude it from google search by editing robots.txt

```
User Agent: *
Disallow: /category
```

Look up google on robots.txt for more details...

Comment: What about for Drupal's search?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how well it works, but have you checked [search config module](http://drupal.org/project/search_config)?